# Solving $x^y = y^x$ analytically in terms of the Lambert $W$ function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transcendental-equations, lambert-w

I'm interested in deriving the solution for $y$ in terms of $x$ given $x^y = y^x$ using the Lambert $W$ function. [Wolfram Alpha states](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ey%20%3D%20y%5Ex):

$$y = - \frac{x\  W\left(-\frac{\log(x)}{x}\right)}{\log(x)}$$

So far I have done the following:

\begin{align*}
x^y & =  y^x\\
y \log(x) & =  x \log(y)\\
\log(y)/y & =  \log(x)/x\\
\log(y)/y & =  \alpha && (\alpha=\log(x)/x)
\end{align*}

The rest of it is proving the solution for $y$  in the last equation is $y = - W(-\alpha)/\alpha$. I can easily verify the solution but I'm unsure how to derive it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from
$$
\frac{\ln x}{x}=\frac{\ln y}{y}
$$
let $y =\mathrm{e}^{-u}$ we find
$$
u\mathrm{e}^{u} = -\frac{\ln x}{x}
$$
taking the lambert 
we find
$$
u = W\left(-\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)
$$
remember $u=-\ln y = -\frac{y}{x}\ln x$
so we get
$$
-\frac{y}{x}\ln x = W\left(-\frac{\ln x}{x}\right) \implies y = \frac{-xW\left(-\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)}{\ln x}
$$

Comment: This is awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: How can I get $y=-4$ from $x=-2$ here?

Comment: @user286485 You can't, because this solution is only about positive numbers

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to apply logarythm on both sides.
$$
x^y=y^x\\
e^{y\ln x}y^{-x}=1\\
e^{\frac{y\ln x}{-x}}y=1\\
e^{\frac{y\ln x}{-x}}\frac{y\ln x}{-x}=\frac{\ln x}{-x}\\
\frac{y\ln x}{-x}=W\left({\frac{\ln x}{-x}}\right)\\
y=\frac{-xW\left({\frac{\ln x}{-x}}\right)}{\ln x}
$$